# Should I bring up that my probation period is over?

Tags: career-development, salary, probation

Today is my 6th month at my entry level job and I was told I'd be given a raise.

I want to bring this up with my boss. Should I wait for the boss to remember or should I bring it up?

This is a new startup and I think my boss is new to the whole process so he may have forgotten.

EDIT: I'm not asking for advice on how to get a raise, I'm asking if I should wait for my boss to remember that my probation is over or should I bring it up to him?

Comment: You generally don't get what you don't ask for.

Comment: I remember lack of assertiveness has been pointed out as a reason of income disparity between men and women: women are statistically less likely to confront their company in an assertive way. Another study I heard of says there's no difference in this regard though. 

So there is proof to back up the idea that you should ask for it. 

Especially since you were promised it so it's not like he can think you are overdoing it, not much risk, if you aren't aggressive.

I won't publish this as an answer as I have nothing to back it up.

Comment: I think these are different, this is focused more on "should I bring it up?" and the linked question and its duplicate are more "how to ask for raise."

Comment: I don't see that personally, but that's why it requires 5  votes. :)  (or yours)

Comment: @Enderland - what should I do is off topic though...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bring it up, politely. Ask for a word with your boss, mention the probation period being over, and suggest a meeting to review things - how well you've been doing, what your plans are and what the company's plans for you are, salary levels, that sort of thing. If you get it scheduled, some sort of meeting should happen where you can remind them that there was some sort of promise of a raise (having this somewhere in writing may help) - which may mean a raise, or may mean them saying no, but at least that's a decision. Without scheduling a meeting, end-of-probation/annual reviews can easily become the sort of thing that gets put off for month after month.

Also: Congratulations on 6 months in the job!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I wait for the boss to remember or should I bring it up?

There is a low likelihood your boss will remember to do this. I would be shocked unless your boss put a reminder on his/her calendar that they even would remember it.

Many bosses would feel bad if you wait 12 months too. It's a way bigger deal to you than your boss. For you, it might be a lot of money. For your boss, it's just a budget

If you have any sort of regular 1x1, bring it up in that. If you feel it would be awkward make sure to read through [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1025/2322) and its answers. They will provide input as well.

Most likely though it'll be a simple conversation, especially if it was in your contract.